How can I avoid this error trying to get a response from the OpenAI API?
I'm trying to get a response from chat GPT in python.
I tried this code block:
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(api_key="sk-proj-0Xo*******************************qOd")

def chat_with_chatgpt(prompt, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
    response = client.completions.create(engine=model,
    prompt=prompt,
    max_tokens=100,
    n=1,
    stop=None,
    temperature=0.5)

    message = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    return message

prompt = "Tell me about yourself"
response = chat_with_chatgpt(prompt)
print(response)

And got this error :
Exception has occurred: TypeError
Missing required arguments; Expected either ('model' and 'prompt') or ('model', 'prompt' and 'stream') arguments to be given
  File "C:\Users\Gareth\OneDrive - Green Spirit Ltd\Desktop\Python\test.py", line 6, in chat_with_chatgpt
    response = client.completions.create(engine=model,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Gareth\OneDrive - Green Spirit Ltd\Desktop\Python\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = chat_with_chatgpt(prompt)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Missing required arguments; Expected either ('model' and 'prompt') or ('model', 'prompt' and 'stream') arguments to be given

I've tried searching the web and directly asking GPT how to fix it, but to no avail. Any help would be massively appreciated!!

Just use "model" instead of "engine".
Note: Don't share the API KEY with the public.
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(api_key="your API key")

def chat_with_chatgpt(prompt, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
    response = client.completions.create(model=model,
    prompt=prompt,
    max_tokens=100,
    n=1,
    stop=None,
    temperature=0.5)

    message = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    return message

prompt = "Tell me about yourself"
response = chat_with_chatgpt(prompt)
print(response)


The engine parameter that you're passing has been deprecated.use "model" instead of "engine".
Please refer the following api doc:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/streaming
